# Getters and setters for arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, getter-setter

I have a few questions about getters and setters for arrays. Suppose we have a class like this, which makes a private copy of an array in its constructor:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo
{
    private int[] array;

    public Foo(int[] array) {
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }
}
```

We want the array to only be accessed/mutated via the getters and setters. If we have a getter that looks like this:

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return array;
}
```

it defeats the purpose of the getter as we're returning a reference that allows the user to directly modify the elements of the array. e.g.

```
Foo foo = new Foo(someArray);
...
int[] bar = foo.getArray();
bar[0] = 123; // Now foo.array[0] = 123 and we haven't used a setter!
```

So presumably we need something like this:

```
public int getElement(int index) {
    return array[index];
}
```

Similarly for setters. But if we're doing things on a per-element basis, we're also going to need to provide a means of getting the length:

```
public int getArrayLength() {
    return array.length;
}
```

This is already a little messy for a 1-dimensional array, but say we have a multidimensional array instead:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Foo
{
    private int[][][] array;

    public Foo(int[][][] array) {
        // Code for making a deep copy here
    }

    public int getElement(int i, int j, int k) {
        return array[i][j][k];
    }

    public void setElement(int i, int j, int k, int value) {
        array[i][j][k] = value;
    }

    public int getArrayLength() {
        return array.length;
    }

    public int getArrayLength(int i) {
        return array[i].length;
    }

    public int getArrayLength(int i, int j) {
        return array[i][j].length;
    }
}
```

This is a lot of code for such a trivial task, and more importantly it's a mess to actually use. Do we really have to end up with something like this, or is there a better way to do it? I've looked all over the place and there doesn't seem to be a "standard practice" for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A multi-dimensional array is also a 1-dimensional array: `int[a][b][c]` is really just `int[a*b*c]`, so the problem boils down to, how do you provide access safely? Simply like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int[] array;

    public Foo(int[] array) {
        this.array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    /** @return a copy of the array */
    public int[] getArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }
}
```

That's it.

Callers have a safe copy of the array and can use it in the full normal way arrays are used. No need for delegator methods.

Comment: What if the array is null? doesn't it throw null pointer exception?

Comment: @Brooklyn99 If the array can be null, of course cater for it: `return array == null ? null : Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);`

Answer (score 1):

What do you think `ArrayList` does, or `Vector` before it?

I think the better question is why, at this point, are you exposing that `Foo` is backed by an array at all?  If you're trying to encapsulate it, you don't need to have accessors and setters all over the place.  If you're just trying to create a class wrapper around the array, then I would suggest you have an interface, call it `IntList` or something, and make `Foo` a concrete implementation that's backed by the list.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the first part could your getter not look like the constructor?

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small API for multidimensional generic arrays. There you have getters, setters for each element, whatever your dimensions are.

[MDDAJ on github](https://github.com/timaschew/MDAAJ)

Here is a example: creating a 5 dimensional string array:

```
MDDAPseudo<String> c = new MDDAPseudo<String>(10,20,5,8,15);
c.set("xyz", 0,0,2,1,0); // setter indices: [0][0][2][1][0]
String s = c.get(0,0,0,0,0); // getter indices [0][0][0][0][0]
```

Bohemian already wrote you can use only one dimension. In this case the class PDDAPSeudo internal have one dimension, too. But the API provides you access like a multi dimensional array