# Setter for arrays: public data assigned to private array

Tags: java, arrays

Related with https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/496.html

Googling a bit led me to we shouldn't get/set private arrays directly from public getters/setters. We can work it around by returning a copy of the array from getters instead of the actual array. And for the getters, we can assign our private arrays to the copy of the array received as an argument in the setter.

Now, I understand that if we use getters, the reference to the array is out and could be modified anytime.

```
private int[] arr = {1,2,3}; 
public int[] getArray() {
    return arr;
}
```

Somewhere else where the class is accessible, doing this:

```
int[] badArray = obj.getArray();
badArray[0] = 100;
```

modifies the `private arr`. 
My question is how else the array could be harmed. That is, if I modify my getter to:

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
}
```

and keep my setter as:

```
public void setArray(int[] arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}
```

How could this be risky for my private array. Please explain with an example.
Related: [Getters and setters for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665150/getters-and-setters-for-arrays)

Comment: Set array -> let application keep running -> make changes to the array, which was used in `setArray(int[])` -> application broken? In other words, just because your (may) fixed `getArray` it doesn't mean I can't still manipulate the array I passed in `setArray`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep your setter as :

```
public void setArray(int[] arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
}
```

The caller of the setter holds a reference to the same array instance stored within you class instance, and can modify it directly.

```
YourClass obj = new YourClass ();
int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3};
obj.setArray (arr);
arr[0] = 5; // this will modify the array stored inside obj
```

You can overcome this issue if you create a copy of the array in your setter too:

```
public void setArray(int[] arr) {
    this.arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
}
```

And for the more general case of arrays of mutable reference types (unlike your primitive int array example), even if you prevent the private array from being modified, the objects whose references are being held in the array can still be modified from outside your class (unless your setter and getter make copies of them too).

Comment: Similar problem is faced for data structures like maps and lists. Then should I make a full copy of them and return instead of returning a reference to the original?

Comment: @AkeshwarJha You can either make a copy, or supply methods that manipulate the Map/List indirectly. For example, instead of a `getMap` method that returns the Map, you can have a `get(key)` method that returns the value for a given key, and a `getKeyList()` method that returns a List (or array) of the keys. If you want to supply methods to mutate the map, you can add an add(key,value)` method (and similarly a remove method). This way your class controls all access and modifications of its internal Map.

Comment: One more doubt please. How effective is cloning instead of Arrays.copy for getters and setters? Given that I only have the array of primitive data type?