# Will the byte array be assigned properly in this manner?

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

I have lost touch with programming for a while, and am now trying to get back to it.

I came across a demo code doing assignment, copying from array to array via for loop. May I know if the below assignment will create error? If it will, is there a cleaner method than doing for loop? Thanks!

```
private byte[] key;   

public void setKey (byte[] newKey){
        this.key = newKey;

}
```

Comment: `key` will hold a reference to `newKey`, so whatever changes you make to `key` will also change in `newKey`.

Comment: I agree with @Logan - this code makes `key` a reference to the identical array object that was passed as an argument to `setKey()`. (It does not copy the array itself.) Whether this "will create an error" depends on whether a reference to the array is kept anywhere else in the code and, if so, how the multiple references are used.

Comment: Will it cause an error?  Maybe?  We need context.  This doesn't *copy* an array, it just creates another reference to the same memory space.

Comment: I realised "create error" creates confusion. I should have state I would like to copy the array from newKey to key. @Abdullah Wasi answered my question below. Thanks folks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign array using the following method

```
public void setKey (byte[] newKey){
    this.key = Arrays.copyOf(newKey, newKey.length);
}
```

You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665150/getters-and-setters-for-arrays) question for better understanding

Comment: Without knowing what OP's code is supposed to be used for, this might actually cause a problem, not solve one. (Also, the second argument to `copyOf()` should be `newKey.length`, not `key.length`.)

Comment: I was just explaining to him how the assignment can properly be done.Updated my answer, thanks ted.

Comment: But this might not be proper. It may be important to store a reference to a specific array object, not a copy of one. As I said, without knowing the context, it's impossible to say which is the right approach.